# FriendlyID for child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I have a Project model that belongs to a User. A User has_many Projects. I have setup FriendlyID according to the gem instructions for User model, however it is not working in this scenario.

```
<%= link_to gravatar_for(project.user, size: 50), project.user %>
```

The above creates a link with the numerical ID of the user (project.user) instead of a friendly URL (i.e. http://localhost:3000/users/102 instead of what I want, http://localhost:3000/users/*random-gen-string*).

`User.rb` file:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :generated_slug, use: :slugged

  def generated_slug
    require 'securerandom'
    @random_slug ||= persisted? ? friendly_id : SecureRandom.hex(15)
  end
```

I think the problem is that `project.user` is set in the `projects_controller.rb` to the user ID (via `current_user.projects.build`...). If I could somehow access the Friendly ID for User in the `projects_controller.rb` I may be able to save it in the database and access it like `project.user_friendly_id`. Not sure..

Relevant code in projects_controller:

```
def create
 @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)
 # code
end
```

What is the best way to go about making the above link link to the Friendly ID and not the user (i.e. http://localhost:3000/users/*random-gen-string* is what I want instead of http://localhost:3000/users/102)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

As discussed in the chatroom, `User.find_each(&:save!)` reveals the errors when saving the `User` model. In the above case, the lack of password input was preventing the `User` records from being saved. Removing the validation temporarily allowed saving the `User` and thus regenerating slugs.

(Original answer left for history)
You can override the `to_param` method in your `User` model like this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # some code

  def to_param
    slug
  end
```

And then that is used to generate the link. More on that in [the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters).

Comment: Do I need to change project.user to something? I tried the above code, (using generated_slug instead of slug) and project.user returned nill. "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]"

Comment: `user_path(slug: project.user.slug)` probably.

Comment: Isn't the slug generated at this time? You might want to check that too.

Comment: I just checked, my existing users at least have "slug: nil". I ran this: User.find_each(&:save) / but still slugs are nill

Comment: What are you trying to do in your `generated_slug` method, I think the problem must be in there. You can just have it return `SecureRandom.hex(15)` since friendly_id doesn't update the slug unless you set it to `nil` yourself.

Comment: Generated slug is just trying to create a random string for user as a slug. I tried returning just SecureRandom.hex(15) and running User.find_each(&:save) but the users' still have slug: nil

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131929/discussion-between-richard-and-iceman).

Answer (score 0):

When you build your link_to you can call the user.slug to ensure that you get the proper info

```
<%= link_to gravatar_for(project.user, size: 50), project.user.slug %>
```

that will generate the link that you are expecting  http://localhost:3000/users/*random-gen-string*

Comment: `gravatar_for` is for displaying the image, the second part is the url, `project.user`

Comment: then just move the slug for the proper part of the `link_to`, Good Eye

Comment: That doesn't produce a working link, slug is just a string and will create `a href='some slug'`

Comment: <%= link_to gravatar_for(project.user, size: 50), project.user.slug %>
 I believe "project.user.slug" evaluates to nil because after I do this the link just points to the root URL

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of cities with increasing order of specificity.

```
 def slug_candidates
[
  :name,
  [:name, :city],
  [:name, :street, :city],
  [:name, :street_number, :street, :city]
]
```

end

In case of conflicting slugs it is better to use user-friendly names then UUID (e.g. 2bc2-d3dd-4f29-b2ad)